# Why is google test EXPECT_EXIT yielding me the wrong error code?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, exit, googletest

I have a function that returns nothing, but based on various conditions will exit the process by calling exit(1). So I duly added an EXPECT_EXIT to my test program,

```
EXPECT_EXIT(checkAndExit(), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(1), ".*");
```

and when I run it I get this:

Result: died but not with expected exit code:
            Exited with exit status 23

Which is interesting, because I most definitely exit(1);
This is on ubuntu 16.04. When I run the same code on osx, it works correctly, it returns 1 and the test passes.

I sifted a bit through the google test source code and nothing popped out at me. Any ideas?

Comment: On Ubuntu your code might be reaching an `exit` that isn't the one you expect. Without an [mcve] can only speculate.

Comment: It's a 3 line function: there's an if, a printf, and an exit. hard to get that wrong. So far though, it's not consistent, I rebuild then it works for a while...